# Can's initiate Jenkins using stable/helm

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to setup Jenkins with stable/helm charts but Jenkins pod always remains in Init status and doesn't give any errors while I am describing the Jenkins pod. I am not able to debug is as it's in Init status.

I have already created PV & PVC and assigned PVC in values files. 
Below is my configuration:

````
master:
  componentName: "jenkins-master"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "lts"
  imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
  lifecycle:
  numExecutors: 0
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  useSecurity: true

  enableXmlConfig: true
  securityRealm: |-
    <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LegacySecurityRealm"/>
  authorizationStrategy: |-
     <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
       <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
     </authorizationStrategy>
  hostNetworking: false
  adminUser: "admin"
  adminPassword: "admin"
  rollingUpdate: {}
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "2048Mi"
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  serviceType: NodePort
  serviceAnnotations: {}
  deploymentLabels: {}
  serviceLabels: {}
  podLabels: {}
  nodePort: 32323
  healthProbes: true
  healthProbesLivenessTimeout: 5
  healthProbesReadinessTimeout: 5
  healthProbeLivenessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeReadinessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 5
  healthProbeReadinessFailureThreshold: 3
  healthProbeLivenessInitialDelay: 90
  healthProbeReadinessInitialDelay: 60
  slaveListenerPort: 50000
  slaveHostPort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  cli: false
  slaveListenerServiceType: "ClusterIP"
  slaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
  slaveKubernetesNamespace:

  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  extraPorts:
  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.18.1
    - workflow-job:2.33
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - credentials-binding:1.19
    - git:3.11.0
    - blueocean:1.18.1
    - kubernetes-cd:2.0.0

  enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: false
  scriptApproval:
  initScripts:
  jobs: {}
  JCasC:
    enabled: false
    pluginVersion: "1.27"
    supportPluginVersion: "1.18"
    configScripts:
      welcome-message: |
        jenkins:
          systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.

  customInitContainers: []

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      enabled: false
      image: shadwell/k8s-sidecar:0.0.2
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources: {}
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  podAnnotations: {}

  customConfigMap: false
  overwriteConfig: false

  overwriteJobs: false

  ingress:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    hostName:
    tls:

  backendconfig:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    name:
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    spec: {}

  route:
    enabled: false
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}

  additionalConfig: {}

  hostAliases: []

  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    serviceMonitorAdditionalLabels: {}
    scrapeInterval: 60s
    scrapeEndpoint: /prometheus
    alertingRulesAdditionalLabels: {}
    alertingrules: []

agent:
  enabled: true
  image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave"
  tag: "3.27-1"
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  imagePullSecretName:
  componentName: "jenkins-slave"
  privileged: false
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
  alwaysPullImage: false
  podRetention: "Never"
  envVars:
  volumes:
  nodeSelector: {}

  command:
  args:
  sideContainerName: "jnlp"
  TTYEnabled: false
  containerCap: 10
  podName: "default"
  idleMinutes: 0
  yamlTemplate:

persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: jenkins-pvc
  storageClass:
  annotations: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "2Gi"
  volumes:
  mounts:

networkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name:
  annotations: {}

serviceAccountAgent:
  create: false
  name:
  annotations: {}

backup:
  enabled: false
  componentName: "backup"
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  annotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: "jenkins"
  image:
    repository: "nuvo/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.1.2"
  extraArgs: []
  existingSecret: {}
  env:
  - name: "AWS_REGION"
    value: "us-east-1"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
  destination: "s3://nuvo-jenkins-data/backup"
checkDeprecation: true```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently had this issue while trying to run Jenkins using helm.  The issue was that the pod couldn't inintialize because of an error that occurred while Jenkins was trying to configure itself and pull updates down from jenkins.io.  You can find these log messages using a command similar to the following:

```
kubectl logs solemn-quoll-jenkins-abc78900-xxx -c copy-default-config
```

Replace `solemn-quoll-jenkins-abc78900-xxx` above with whatever name helm assigns to your jenkins pod.  The issue was in the `copy-default-config` container, so the `-c` option allows you to peek at the logs of this container within the jenkins pod.  In our case, it was an http proxy issue where the `copy-default-config` container was failing because it could not connect to https://updates.jenkins.io/ to download updates for plugins.  You can test if it is a plugin update issue by going into your values.yaml file and commenting out all the plugins under the `installPlugins:` heading in the yaml file.

For example:

```
  installPlugins:
  #- kubernetes:1.18.1
  #- workflow-job:2.33
  #- workflow-aggregator:2.6
  #- credentials-binding:1.19
  #- git:3.11.0
  #- blueocean:1.18.1
  #- kubernetes-cd:2.0.0
```